# ios JSON parses string values to <null>

Tags: php, ios, json, ios6, nsjsonserialization

My app receives a json response from my php web service, containing an array of data.
If I print out the array in the webservice I receive the following in my app which looks fine.

```
NSLog(@"data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloaddata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => some title //MySQL varchar(60), utf8_unicode_ci
            [description] => some description //MySQL text, utf8_unicode_ci
            [type] => AUDIO //MySql enum
            [created] => 2013-02-25 00:00:00
            [edited] => 2013-02-25 00:00:00
            [version] => 1
            [courserooms_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => some other title
            [description] => some other description
            [type] => MOVIE
            [created] => 2013-02-12 00:00:00
            [edited] => 2013-02-14 00:00:00
            [version] => 1
            [courserooms_id] => 1
        )
```

In iOS i parse the received data using NSJSONSerialization.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:downloaddata

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    NSLog(@"json: %@", json);
}
```

Output:

In the output the string values of the array are null and I dont know why.

```
{
            "courserooms_id" = 1;
            created = "2013-02-25 00:00:00";
            description = "<null>";
            edited = "2013-02-25 00:00:00";
            id = 3;
            title = "<null>";
            type = AUDIO;
            version = 1;
        },
                {
            "courserooms_id" = 1;
            created = "2013-02-12 00:00:00";
            description = "<null>";
            edited = "2013-02-14 00:00:00";
            id = 4;
            title = "<null>";
            type = MOVIE;
            version = 1;
        }
```

My php webservice returns the content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Any idea why the strings parse to null ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try checking your JSON on this website http://jsonlint.com/ just paste you JSON code and Validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
The problem was that i didn't set the charset in the mysql query on my php web service. 
In my database i used the collation latin1_swedish_ci. The values in my db contained some chars like 'ü' 'ä' etc. which could not be decoded right in my ios app.
After preparing my queries with the following statement:

```
$query->prepare("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

The response from my service was in utf-8 encoding, and i could just declare NSStrings out of the json response, because NSStrings uses utf-8 encoding by default.

So the problem had to do with incorrect encoding of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Set the encoding as NSUTF8StringEncoding. It may solve your problem.

NSLog(@"data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloaddata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);